# "location.reload();" not working

Tags: reactjs, class, refresh, create-react-app

i need to refresh the page the moment the class is open because it wont show unless i refresh the page. heres what i got.

```
class PulseClass extends Component {
  render (){
    return(
      <div className="app">
        <div className="Sborder Pulse">
          <div className="sec1">
            <div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="sec2">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
          *{location.reload();}*
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

im trying to do this with location reload.
any tips?

Comment: class PulseClass extends Component {
  render (){
    return(
      <div className="app">
        <div className="Sborder Pulse">
          <div className="sec1">
            <div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div><div>
              hey
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="sec2">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
          {location.reload();}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: put your code properly in a code block. It's impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: yea im still very new to stackoverflow

Comment: Well, if you need to refresh the page for the content to show, something is not working to begin with. Why do you think that's necessary?  Either way, the reload shouldn't be called inside your render method, it will create an infinite loop.

Comment: yea, i noticed, im gonna have to look into it more

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code for reloading the page. Hope it helps you.

`window.location.reload();`

Comment: Helped me. It works if anyone getting problem while using in react.

Instead of window.reload() or location.reload(). It worked well

Answer (score 1):

In place of location.reload() use document.location.reload();